# dlib functions to parse ImgLab files

Tags: python, dlib

I have used `dlib`'s ImgLab tool to annotate some images, so its produced an XML annotation file. I then used this for `dlib`'s simple object detector but it did quite bad. So I want to train my own SVM where I have more control over feature extraction.

I want to use the same annotation XML file for my own feature extraction. Does `dlib` have functions to parse the XML file and extract the boxes/annotations?

I know I can write my own XML parser but I would much prefer to not reinvent the wheel is dlib has functions to extract these. I have searched the dlib site but cannot find dlib python functions for parsing - anyone know a link?

Answer (score 0):

The methods for reading those XML files are documented here: http://dlib.net/ml.html#load_image_dataset_metadata. The Python API has the same methods with the same names.